# Call constructor using auto on the left side

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, auto

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A {
    A() { cout << "default" << endl; }
    A(const A&) { cout << "copy" << endl; }
    A(A&&) { cout << "move" << endl; }

};
int main() {
    A a{};
    auto aa = A{};
    return 0;
}
```

This program will print `default`, `default` in MSVC2013. Does the standard say anything of creating an object with auto on the left side, or can the second version, `auto aa = A{};` first call the default constructor and then move/copy the tmp variable to the left side?

Comment: Look [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/031371d6a96bbb4d). Notice that I used the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag. What you're seeing is called copy elision, search for that and you'll find several answers explaining what it is. And `auto` is completely orthogonal to the issue, you'll see the same behavior even if you use `A` instead.

Comment: is the copy elision optional for the compiler to do? or is it in the standard that it has to?

Comment: I do not know of any case where copy elision is mandatory.

Comment: This is not exactly a dupp.